# Flutter - Issue with hiding system bars

Tags: flutter

I want to build full-screen app. I've done it with     **SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);**

But i have pain in ass with back gesture. When i swipe on the edge, before system bars appear and only after i can swipe to back

[image]